# "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." while using spark-submit

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-spark, command-line, spark-submit

I am using spark-submit to execute a jar file. Spark is located in my "C" drive and my eclipse workspace is in "D" drive. Tough I am giving an absolute path for the jar file I get the error saying "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Below is the command i used to run spark-submit:

```
C:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin>spark-submit --class "Main" --master local[2] "
D:\JAVA NEW ENV\Line_Count_Spark\target\Line_Count_Spark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

What is exactly wrong with this and is there any workaround for the same?

Comment: `C:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin>spark-submit --class "Main" --master local[2] jar/location`. No quotes in path

Comment: Actually I have spaces in my workspace folder name. I edited the earlier mentioned path above

Comment: `C:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin>spark-submit --class "Main" --master local[2] 
D:\JAVA^ NEW^ ENV\Line_Count_Spark\target\Line_Count_Spark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`. escaping the space with a `caret symbol`.

Comment: Still it is throwing the error

'C:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin\spark-submit2.cmd" --class "Main' is not recog
nized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: specify class name along with package for example `com.test.Main` where `com.test` is my package and `Main` is my class where I have `main()`

Comment: My package is default package. I tried giving it but it shows the same error
`C:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin>spark-submit --class "default.Main" --master local[2] C:\test\Line_Count_Spark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
'C:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin\spark-submit2.cmd" --class "default.Main' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: It worked when I removed quotes for class name. I tried it without giving package name. Thanks for quick reply

Answer (score 3):

try "spark-submit2"

```
spark-submit2 --class "Main" --master local[2] "D:\JAVA NEW ENV\Line_Count_Spark\target\Line_Count_Spark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

Comment: we faced the same problem when we pass multiple jars in double quotes with comma separated, spark-submit.cmd throwing an the filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. even though spark-submit.cmd internally calls spark-submit2.cmd seems some issue. the moment switching to spark-submit2 every thing fine.